# Zeppelin isolated per user mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

My question is about the isolated mode per user in zeppelin.

If zeppelin doesn't yet support the deploy-mode remote for spark driver( more info in [ZEPPELIN-2040](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2040))

how you deal with multiple users so multiple spark driver with each one take 4GB of memory ?

I'am looking for a horizontal scalable solution without increasing the spark master instance memory and use the slaves memory for driver.

Comment: http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/usage/interpreter/interpreter_binding_mode.html Create spark intp with 4GB memory option and set it as isolated mode. This doc will guide u about the basic concepts of interpreter modes.

Comment: the problem isn't the creation of an interpreter with isolated mode, but use the isolated mode with a remote interpreter